# FQL Not returning anything

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get:

- likes count of page
- posts count of page
- posts likes count of page

I'm using the following PHP script:

```
<?php
# Error Printing
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

require_once('FacebookAPI/Facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy',
));

# Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$fql  = "SELECT like_info.like_count, comment_info.comment_count, share_count, post_id
         FROM stream 
         WHERE source_id = 'PAGE_ID'";
$param  =   array(
                  'method'    => 'fql.query',
                  'query'     => $fql,
                  'callback'  => ''
                  );
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
$asset_count = 0;
foreach($fqlResult as $row){
    $asset_count += (int)$row['like_info.like_count'] + (int)$row['comment_info.comment_count']+ (int)$row['share_count']+ (int)$row['post_id'];               
}
echo "<br/><br/>";
echo $asset_count;
?>
```

But it's returning a blank screen, what's wrong with it?
It's not printing any errors either, although I enabled error logging/printing:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: Make a debug output of return values via `var_dump`, and also check if any exceptions are thrown by the API calls (meaning, use proper try-catch statements.)

Comment: var_dump everything starting from getting user ID. You could possible encounter that your library uses deprecated api calls and thus does not return anything. Or you can have simple misspelling anywhere.